# how to add the value of an input field as a value in a multidimensional array using angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="sItems in items">
   <td>{{sItems.item_name}}</td>
   <td>{{sItems.item_category_name}}</td>
   <td>{{sItems.item_price}}</td>
   <td><input type="number" name="itemQty" id="itemQty" class="form-control" value="0" ng-model="itemQty" ng-change="createBag(sItems)"></td>
</tr>
```

AngularJS APP

```
var app = angular.module('BCApp', []);
      app.controller('requestPickupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('modules/show_items_price.php').then(function(response) {
          $scope.items = response.data.itemsRecords;
        });
        $scope.bag_array = [];
        $scope.createBag = function(xcreate) {
          $scope.bag_array.push({
            "item_name"   :   xcreate.item_name, 
            "item_qty"    :   $scope.itemQty, 
            "item_price"  :   xcreate.item_price
          });
        }
      });
```

In the angular js app, I'm trying to create records in the json array "bag_array". It's working for other columns, except column "item_qty". I want to insert the final value of the input field into column "item_qty" but it's not working. The column just remains empty. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ng-model="sItems.itemQty"`: you want each input field to be bound to a separate variable, instead of all sharing the same model.Not sure why you add a new bag every time the value changes though.

Comment: @JBNizet i'm not adding a new bag every time the value changes, i'm only updating the bag (adding new items)..

Comment: Yes, sorry. I guess the `createBag` name for the function misguided me. Still, I don't understand why you add a new item to the bag every time the value changes.

Comment: it's a laundry pickup app.. so, each time the user selects a laundry item (by changing its quantity from 0 to 1), the item is added to the preview pane (the bag).